# Bigger threadpool or additional ExecutorService when new kind of thread will run?

Tags: java, concurrency, multithreading, overhead, executorservice

I have a question that is related to possible overhead of `ExecutorService`s in Java.

The present implementation has `ExecutorService A` with a capacity of 5 threads.

- It runs threads of type `A`.
- type `A` threads do some database reading and writing.

Now, a thread of type `B` will run after **some** threads of type `A` has finished.

- The number of type `B` threads that will run is different from time to time.
- type `B` threads do some filesystem IO (not database).

So should I

- add a new `ExecutorService` to handle type `B` threads
- or should I increase the capacity of `ExecutorService A` and run type `B` threads with that one as well?

I'm thinking that there might be some extra overhead for Java to have two `ExecutorService`s, but on the other hand the total number of threads will increase either way. Does it matter at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will recommend two `ExecutorServices`, then you can take advantage of the different `ExecutorService`s provided by the `java.util.concurrent` package.

It makes the code easier and the overhead is ignorable.

- `ExecutorService` a with a fixed thread pool set to five threads.
- `ExecutorService` b with a cached thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about 5 threads, and you're not exhausting your thread pool capacity, I would tend to say that the overhead woulld be insignificant either way, and you should just go whatever you deem to be the simplest route.

Comment: that reasoning makes sense. I will do another ExecutorService because it feels like cleaner code in general.